# High-dimensional dependent binary explanatory variable

Tags: feature-selection, large-data, binary-data, independence

I am dealing with a data set containing roughly $n=4000$ **binary** observations $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ with $p=1000$ **binary** explanatory variables. I suspect that a lot of these explanatory variables are not relevant to the prediction of the observations. Moreover, it is clear that there are certain groups of explanatory variables that are very highly correlated.

What are the usual approaches to deal with these kinds of situation. Indeed, quick simulations show that classical logistic regression and SVM do not work too well. Is there any method that can tackle the identification of these groups of highly correlated binary variables at the same time that the model is fitted to the data. I am looking something in the spirit of the LASSO that can do variable selection and model fitting at the same time.

Comment: What is the dependent variable? Have you considered some regularized regression (e.g. lasso, ridge regression)? Such approaches are often useful when you think, a priori, that "a lot of these explanatory variables are not relevant to the prediction of the observations".

Comment: @Macro: thanks for your comments. I have added some details.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches.

The first is to use substantive knowledge to eliminate some of the IVs.

Partial least squares is one possibility; principal component analysis of the IVs is another. Both of these create new variables that are linear combinations of the original IVs.

If you want to keep the original IVs, but just eliminate some of them, then one method is to look for IVs that are very highly correlated and remove one of each pair.